# IntelliJ Idea - Cannot find input file(bank.in) when running through IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, windows-10, bufferedreader, filereader

I have a homework and I did it on Linux, Visual Studio Code, and the command line. It was working perfectly fine until I need to debug my code. So I migrated to Windows 10 because I had IntelliJ IDEA installed there. I compiled the code and place the input file "bank.in" in the same folder as the compiled "MyClass.class"

However, when I run the program from IntelliJ, my code catches the exception that it cannot find the file "bank.in" when it is just in the same folder as "MyClass.class".

My method in creating the bank.in was, right clicking the out folder from IntelliJ and adding a new file and adding the bank.in contents from there

I've tried running it through cmd.exe using `java MyClass` and it works perfectly. No exceptions are caught.

But when run through IntelliJ IDEA, it shows

```
    Cannot find bank.in...

    Exiting the program...
```

This is the part of my code where I input my file.

```
public void main(String[] args)
{
    String fileName = "bank.in";

    FileReader bank = null;
    BufferedReader bankBuffered = null;

    try
    {
        bank = new FileReader(fileName);
        bankBuffered = new BufferedReader(bank);
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException f)
    {
        System.out.printf("%s is not found.%n%n", fileName);
        System.out.printf("Exiting the program...%n");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

This is my project folder structure

```
MyProject
-.idea
    -encodings.xml
    -misc.xml
    -modules.xml
    -workspace.xml
-out
    -MyClass.class
    -bank.in
-src
    -MyClass.java
```

When I run it through cmd.exe, it works fine. Is there any workaround through this? Thank you.

Comment: Edit your run configration to have the working directory as the out-directory. It's probably something completely different now making you not find the file.

Comment: @trappski It worked. Pointed my Working directory from `MyProject` to `MyProject\out\production\MyProject`... Thank you!